# Is Oracle ODAC Installaition requires Seperate License

Tags: oracle, odac

We need to use Oracle ODAC to connect oracle database from our client application. Also we need to deploy many user's PC to work with our applications. ODAC is a freeware or requires separate license? Please advise.. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

ODAC is completely free.  You need to create an account to download it, but the download itself, and the use of the software, is free.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Please be sure to mark this as the correct answer :D